# How can i make a div class a certain color, while staying within certain grids?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 2-8-2 grid going on. I want the 2 on each side to stay white, while the 8 grid in the middle changes to a feint gray.

What I have Tried:

HTML

```
<div class = "name"  class="col-sm-8 text-left">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.name{
  background-color: #gray; (or any other color) 
}
```

My results are, in the div, only one of the classes will work at a time. Either it will give me the color of the entire grid, or it will give me no color depending on the order of `class="name"` and `class="col-sm-8 textleft"`

Answer (score 0):

change: 
`<div class = "name"  class="col-sm-8 text-left" >`

into:
`<div class = "name col-sm-8 text-left" >`

if the rest of css and html is ok it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're duplicating the `class` attribute. Instead of

```
class="name" class="col-sm-8 text-left"
```

Change it to

```
class="col-sm-8 text-left name"
```

Only one `class` attribute it allowed on an HTML element, meaning if two are present, one will be ignored; which is why you saw the issue with ordering.

Final code would look something like this:

```
.name {
  background-color: grey;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
      Outer
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-center name">
      Inner
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
      Outer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/KN6MADXKex)